# How to append to each element in the tensor without a loop?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

How to manipulate each element in a tensor?
For example, `a = [[1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3]]` and `b = [0,0,0]`. Here I want to connect b before each element of a, which will become `[[0,0,0,1,1,1], [0,0,0,2,2,2], [0,0,0,3,3,3]]`, is there a way to implement this without a loop since using loop is pretty slow in python while dealing with large data.
Many thanks.

Comment: `a` is a list of lists, right?  So is the result.  Lists <=> loops.  Now if `a` was np.array(a)`, a (3,3) array, it is easy to concatenate a like size array of zeros.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np
import torch

a = np.array([[1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3]])
b = np.array([0, 0, 0])

result = np.array([np.array((*b, *row)) for row in a])

# Converting to torch
result = torch.from_numpy(result)
```

Result:

```py
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()`:

```py
a = [[1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3]]
b = [0,0,0]

result = list(map(lambda x: b + x, a))

# Prints [[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2], [0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3]]
print(result)
```

Comment: How much does that help?  Isn't still a python loop?

Comment: You're going to need to access all of the data at least once, so _some_ iteration is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [185]: a = [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
     ...: b = [0, 0, 0]
```

The obvious list comprenhensin:

```
In [186]: [b + x for x in a]
Out[186]: [[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2], [0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3]]
```

And array approach:

```
In [187]: np.concatenate((np.zeros((len(a), len(a[0])), int), np.array(a)), axis=1)
Out[187]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3]])
```

for this small example the list approach is better:

```
In [188]: timeit [b + x for x in a]
528 ns ± 12.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
In [189]: timeit np.concatenate((np.zeros((len(a), len(a[0])), int), np.array(a)), axis=1)
9.77 µs ± 95.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

If `A` is already an array:

```
In [192]: %%timeit A = np.array(a)
     ...:  np.concatenate((np.zeros(A.shape,A.dtype), A), axis=1)
6.26 µs ± 223 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

The last will scalar much better.

And the `map` alternative:

```
In [194]: timeit list(map(lambda x: b + x, a))
856 ns ± 31.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```